# How to conconfigure AV1 codec for low delay applications?

Tags: video, video-encoding, video-codecs

Do anyone know how to conconfigure  AV1 for low delay applications , i mean like HM (HEVC) low delay configuration where the GOP is IPPP..( just 2 temporal layers ) ,

I tried these , but i am not sure because it's not different from the regular mode (random access) :

```
aomenc.exe  --profile=0  --auto-alt-ref=0  --lag-in-frames=0   --arnr-maxframes=0 --arnr-strength=5  --static-thresh=0 --passes=2 --pass=1 --end-usage=cq --cq-level=40  --width=352 --height=288  --fpf=aom_QP40.log --cpu-used=4 --threads=8 --limit=10 --fps=25/1 --bit-depth=8  --kf-min-dist=32 --kf-max-dist=32 --psnr  -o output_QP40.webm akiyo_cif.yuv 

aomenc.exe  --profile=0  --auto-alt-ref=0  --lag-in-frames=0   --arnr-maxframes=0 --arnr-strength=5  --static-thresh=0 --passes=2 --pass=2 --end-usage=cq --cq-level=40  --width=352 --height=288  --fpf=aom_QP40.log --cpu-used=4 --threads=8 --limit=10 --fps=25/1 --bit-depth=8  --kf-min-dist=32 --kf-max-dist=32 --psnr  -o output_QP40.webm akiyo_cif.yuv
```

i am using `--kf-min-dist=32 --kf-max-dist=32` because i want an golden frame ( IDR/I-frame like ) to be reproduce each 1 sec for streaming purposes.

Comment: Do you mean low latency or faster turn-around time ? Low delay could mean several things right ? The kf-min-dist and kf-max-dist I think are for key frame settings. Perhaps you could play with the min-gf-interval and max-gf-interval settings.

Comment: Thanks for answering ; yeah i mean low latency, which means in term of encoding , using only backward prediction and no bidirectional inter prediction ( e. g. only P frames and no B frames in hevc ).
so i want to disactivate ALTREF2 and  BWDREF, to keep only ALTREF2 frames ,

Comment: playing with this paras could be the answer but i am not sure :

`--kf-min-dist=<arg>         Minimum keyframe interval (frames)
--kf-max-dist=<arg>         Maximum keyframe interval (frames)
--arnr-maxframes=<arg>      AltRef max frames (0..15)
--min-gf-interval=<arg>     min gf/arf frame interval 
--max-gf-interval=<arg>     
--sframe-dist=<arg>         S-Frame interval (frames)
--sframe-mode=<arg> `
so what doest it means gf/arf frames and S frames ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer. In x265 we have zero latency mode which has only IPPP frames and in VP9 you have to use this command for libvpx *** --arnr-maxframes=0 --arnr-strength=0 --arnr-type=3 --auto-alt-ref=0 --lag-in-frames=0*** I have attached the screenshot from the Bitstream analyzer where you can see ALTREF=0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbMFQ.jpg)